# unable to connect to Alfresco

Tags: connection, port, alfresco, alfresco-share

I installed Alfresco 5.0 on a VM (Centos) in our company. The Alfresco logs look ok and Alfresco is running. But if I try to call the Alfresco-Website from my office Windows PC, i get "unable to connect".
I call the site with http://IP-Adress:8080/share
I first thought that the firewall is blocking port 8080. Other Web Applications like Joomla or Moodle which are also running on the Centos-VM are accessible via web without problems.
I`m stuck here and would appreciate any help.
Here are the results of netstat, iptables and nmap:

There seems to be listening at port 8080:

```
netstat -an | grep 8080 | grep -i listen
tcp 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN
```

Here the output of iptables:

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:http
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:mysql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
```

NMap:

```
[root@SLCTEST alfresco-5.0.d]# nmap -sS -O 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-18 17:11 BRT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000035s latency).
Not shown: 989 closed ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open ssh
25/tcp open smtp
80/tcp open http
139/tcp open netbios-ssn
445/tcp open microsoft-ds
3306/tcp open mysql
5432/tcp open postgresql
7070/tcp open realserver
8009/tcp open ajp13
8080/tcp open http-proxy
8443/tcp open https-alt
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
```

Comment: Are you able to login form localhost? Also have tried after disabling firewall?I do not see any other reason to make it work in same network.

Comment: To be sure look `server.xml` of tomcat and find `<Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1"` if address attribute is listed than remove it. It keeps application restricted to localhost only.

Comment: thanks for reply. No, my server.xml of tomcat doesn`t contain <Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1

Comment: try a netstat -anp to see which processes are using theses ports or check also when alfresco is shut down

Answer (score 0):

Setting up your firewall for traffic that comes from other hosts in the network

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

and change the url request to : http://IP-Adress/share